# How to make elements appear and disappear with animation in a vue component?

Tags: css, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I'm using quasar vue.js framework and have this component:

```
<template>
  <div class="landing-section">
    <div class="landing-section__text-box">
      <p class="landing-section__text-box__title">Albert Pike</p>
      <p class="landing-section__text-box__description">
        Albert Pike (December 29, 1809 – April 2, 1891) was an American author,
        poet, orator, editor, lawyer, jurist, and prominent member of the
        Freemasons. Pike was a senior officer of the Confederate States Army who
        commanded the District of Indian Territory in the Trans-Mississippi
        Theater of the American Civil War.
      </p>
      <q-btn
        class="q-mt-md"
        :to="{ name: 'AboutUs' }"
        padding="0.8rem 2.5rem"
        outline
        rounded
        color="white"
        label="Know More"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.landing-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37rem;
  background: url("https://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/9/a/6/163230.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 20% -1.2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.landing-section__text-box {
  width: 33rem;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}
.landing-section__text-box__title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.landing-section__text-box__description {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.landing-section__text-box__learn-more-button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
::v-deep(.block) {
  font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
```

This is the final result:

[image]

Now i want to add animation to the following elements:
`landing-section__text-box__title`
`landing-section__text-box__description`
`q-btn`

1. The 3 elements should change for example every 3 seconds to display new content especially the title and the description.
2. This change should loop infinitely.

Any help on how can i do this ?

Comment: Did you try to use [`transition`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Transitioning Between Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Elements)

```js
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sections: [{
          title: "Section A",
          description: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        },
        {
          title: "Section B",
          description: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
        }
      ],
      activeSectionIndex: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    activeSection() {
      return this.sections[this.activeSectionIndex]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextSection() {
      this.activeSectionIndex++
      if(this.activeSectionIndex >= this.sections.length) this.activeSectionIndex = 0
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => this.nextSection(), 3000)
  },
  destroyed() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }  
})
```

```css
.slide-fade-enter-active {
  transition: all .8s ease;
}
.slide-fade-leave-active {
  transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}
.slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
/* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
  transform: translateX(10px);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition name="slide-fade" mode="out-in">
    <div :key="activeSection.title">
      <p> {{ activeSection.title }} </p>
      <p> {{ activeSection.description }} </p>
    </div>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: That was very helpful, But why do you use a key as an attribute in the div after the transition tags ? Also is the destory hook now Unmounted in vue v3 ?

Comment: `destroy` was my mistake. It's `destroyed` in Vue 2. And yes in Vue 3 it is renamed to `unmounted` (You didn't tagged the question with Vue 3 tag)

Comment: If you read the docs I linked, `<transition>` component handles so called Enter/Leave transitions (one element/component is entering and other is leaving). To do that, you can use `v-if` and `v-else` OR changing the key (+ any content inside elements). When the key changes, Vue will create new element and destroy the other instead of "patching" old element with the new content (which would not trigger CSS transition)

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

**Note: I am using quasar vuejs framework**

Enabling animations in quasar:

`quasar.conf.js`

```js
animations: "all",
```

`src/store/general/state.js`

```js
export default function () {
  return {
    /* Home Page Landing Section data */
    landingSectionItems: [
      {
        title: `Altiyan Childs`,
        description: `Altijan Juric[2] (born 10 June 1975), best known by his stage name Altiyan Childs, is an Australian singer-songwriter.[3] He was the winner of the second season of The X Factor Australia in 2010.`,
        buttonLink: "AboutUs",
        buttonLabel: "Know More",
      },
      {
        title: `Freemasonry`,
        description: `Freemasonry or Masonry refers to fraternal organisations that trace their origins to the local guilds of stonemasons that, from the end of the 13th century, regulated the qualifications of stonemasons and their interaction with authorities and clients.`,
        buttonLink: "AboutUs",
        buttonLabel: "Know More",
      },
      {
        title: `Satanism`,
        description: `Satanism is a group of ideological and philosophical beliefs based on Satan. Contemporary religious practice of Satanism began with the founding of the atheistic Church of Satan in America in 1966, although a few historical precedents exist.`,
        buttonLink: "AboutUs",
        buttonLabel: "Know More",
      },
    ],

    activeLandingSectionItem: 0,
  };
}
```

`src/store/general/mutations.js`

```js
export const changeLandingSectionItem = (state) => {
  if (state.activeLandingSectionItem >= state.landingSectionItems.length - 1) {
    state.activeLandingSectionItem = 0;
  } else {
    state.activeLandingSectionItem++;
  }
};
```

`src/components/home/LandingSection.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="landing-section">
    <div class="landing-section__text-box">
      <transition name="fade-title" mode="out-in">
        <div :key="items[activeItem].title">
          <p
            class="landing-section__text-box__title"
            v-html="items[activeItem].title"
          ></p>
        </div>
      </transition>
      <transition name="fade-description" mode="out-in">
        <div :key="items[activeItem].title">
          <p class="landing-section__text-box__description">
            {{ items[activeItem].description }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </transition>

      <transition name="fade-button" mode="out-in">
        <div :key="items[activeItem].title">
          <q-btn
            class="q-mt-md"
            :to="{ name: items[activeItem].buttonLink }"
            padding="0.8rem 2.5rem"
            outline
            rounded
            color="white"
            :label="items[activeItem].buttonLabel"
          />
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, onMounted, onUnmounted } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
export default {
  setup() {
    const $store = useStore();
    const items = computed(() => {
      return $store.state.general.landingSectionItems;
    });
    const activeItem = computed(() => {
      return $store.state.general.activeLandingSectionItem;
    });

    const changeItem = () => {
      $store.commit("general/changeLandingSectionItem");
    };

    const changeItemTimer = setInterval(() => {
      changeItem();
    }, 8000);

    onMounted(() => {
      changeItemTimer;
    });

    onUnmounted(() => {
      clearInterval(changeItemTimer);
    });

    return {
      items,
      activeItem,
      changeItem,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.landing-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 37rem;
  background: url("/images/landing-section/landing-img.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 20%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.landing-section__text-box {
  width: 33rem;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.landing-section__text-box__title,
.landing-section__text-box__description,
.landing-section__text-box__learn-more-button {
  color: white;
}
.landing-section__text-box__title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.landing-section__text-box__description {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}
::v-deep(.block) {
  font-weight: 700;
}

/* Animations */

.fade-title-enter-active {
  animation: fadeInDown 1s;
}
.fade-title-leave-active {
  animation: fadeOutUp 1s;
}

.fade-description-enter-active {
  animation: fadeInRight 1s;
}
.fade-description-leave-active {
  animation: fadeOutRight 1s;
}

.fade-button-enter-active {
  animation: fadeInUp 1s;
}
.fade-button-leave-active {
  animation: fadeOutDown 1s;
}
</style>
```